# Проверяет ли данные на сервере метод validate()?

Tags: php, yii, валидация

Один человек мне сказал, что метод validate() проверяет данные только на стороне клиента, что нужно прописывать отдельные проверки для валидации на стороне сервера. Я почему то считал, что validate() производит проверку как на сервере, так и на клиентской части. Кто прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Валидация происходит как на стороне клиента, так и на сервере. 
Подробно все расписано в официальной документации: [Тут](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-)

Цитирую:

> Если вы хотите отключить проверку на стороне клиента полностью, вы можете настроить свойство [[yii\widgets\ActiveForm::enableClientValidation]] установив значение false. Вы также можете отключить проверку на стороне клиента отдельных полей ввода, настроив их с помощью свойства [[yii\widgets\ActiveField::enableClientValidation]] установив значение false.